# Creating stackoverflow kind of Textbox in asp.net ,jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to build control that is similar to stackoverflow. While selecting the tag autocomplete suggestions should be shown and while selecting the textbox get populated with the selected tag and I should be able to delete the tag from the textbox as well.

Can you suggest some free/paid libraries/components which I can integrate and use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excellent plugin for adding tags:

- ([demo](http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/examples.html)) https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it

> A jQuery UI plugin to handle multi-tag fields as well as tag suggestions/autocomplete.
>   
>   Others:

1. ([demo](http://tagedit.webwork-albrecht.de/playground.html)) https://github.com/webworka/Tagedit
2. ([demo](http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/)) https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input
3. ([demo](http://documentcloud.github.com/visualsearch/#demo)) https://github.com/documentcloud/visualsearch/
4. ([demo](http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/)) http://ioncache.github.com/Tag-Handler/
5. ([demo](http://blog.crazybeavers.se/wp-content/Demos/jquery.tag.editor/)) http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jQueryTagEditor
6. ([demo](http://webspirited.com/tagit/)) http://jquery.webspirited.com/2011/02/jquery-tagit-a-jquery-tagging-plugin/
7. ([demo](http://textextjs.com/)) http://textextjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/), JQuery plugin.

You can download the Plugin [here](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/)

Answer (score 0):

Best plugin which i have used and its very simple. Many options to select theme also

([Demo](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/demo.html))[Jquery Tokeninput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/)